# Is there an open source tool for producing bibtex entries from paper PDFs?

Tags: citations, software, tools, reference-managers, bibtex

In the desktop application for Mendeley, it's possible to import a PDF and have the bibliographic data automatically extracted (or perhaps looked up, I'm not sure).  This feature is more or less reliable.  However, Mendeley's code is closed source (they once promised to release the source, but then they were bought by Elsevier).  **I'm looking for an open source tool that takes one or more PDFs as input and returns a bibtex entry for each**.

I've found the following, but couldn't get either of them to work:

- [cb2Bib](http://www.molspaces.com/d_cb2bib-overview.php)
- [pdfmeat](https://code.google.com/p/pdfmeat/)

At present, the fastest alternative I know is to copy/paste the title into Google Scholar, and click the link to bibtex.  That's very nice, but I'm wondering if there is something more automated.

Comment: Have you tried Zotero? In its free version, it can handle a limited number of pdf's at at time but will extract the info from the pdf, provided it exists.

Comment: Be careful with bibtex metadata provided by Google Scholar. Though it is a great tool without a doubt, the bibtex entries may be incomplete and should *at the very least* be proofread prior to publication, assuming you are using those in a paper.

Comment: I got pdfmeat working just now on OS X. Had to modify path to FireFox cookies, and `pip install` what it complained it was missing. P.S. didn't know about that tool. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @PeterJansson Thanks; you should post that as an answer!

Comment: @mankoff I did the same and got pdfmeat to run, but for the paper I tried it just launched a totally nonsensical GScholar search and came up with nothing.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42361/citation-manager

Comment: @StrongBad Thanks for the link; I agree!  If they are willing to migrate that here, we can delete my question.  Otherwise, perhaps it is worthwhile to have it appear on both sites.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson it seems like a big list type question to me so I am not sure it is a great fit here. I will check about migrating it here when I get a chance. It might be worth asking what to do in our meta.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson A quick Google search turned up at least 20 unique ways of extracting metadata from a PDF file. Not all are open source, but it seems like a number might be.

Comment: This question of mine on TeX.SE and specially [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194963/52417) may also help you: [website for easy creating biblatex code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194816/website-for-easy-creating-biblatex-code).

Comment: @MarcClaesen, treat *all* BibTeX entries you get from elsewhere with suspicion. E.g. the BibTeX entries given by ACM for their publications are uniformly atrocious (wrong capitalization, useless fields, the works).

Comment: The question is now also raised at tex.stackexchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/344081/9075

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) which in itself is a system for handling references, it comes as both a plugin to Firefox and as standalone. I use the standalone version to extract reference information from pdf and then export to, in my case, BibTeX `.bib` format. There are possibilities to export to other formats as well.

Answer (score 12):

This doesn't answer your entire question, but may be useful (for example, you might have got the papers from a list of DOIs in the first place).

Assuming these are PDFs with CrossRef DOIs, if you can extract the DOI from the PDF, you can get citation directly from CrossRef's API. For the DOI `10.5555/12345678`, the query:

```
http://api.crossref.org/works/10.5555/12345678/transform/application/x-bibtex
```

returns

```
@article{Carberry_2008,
    doi = {10.5555/12345678},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.5555/12345678},
    year = 2008,
    month = {aug},
    publisher = {{CrossRef}},
    volume = {5},
    number = {11},
    pages = {1--3},
    author = {Josiah Carberry},
    title = {Toward a Unified Theory of High-Energy Metaphysics: Silly String Theory},
    journal = {Journal of Psychoceramics}
}
```

You could write a very small script to scan a list of DOIs and download the citations.

Comment: The month entry should be integer.

Answer (score 5):

NB: My answer does not differentiate between open and closed sourced projects and I have not used any of the seemingly big list of solutions.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523416/2787723) suggests that the 2010 London Dev8D meeting, whatever that is, ran a contest for meta data extraction and resulted in [pdfssa4met](https://code.google.com/p/pdfssa4met/). I cannot find any documentation on the meeting and anything else that came out of it. The JISC ConnectedWorks project produced a [review document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bmVV89ZozeYsboSTTebKXv3u2vUDAmY3rG2tr5IIl0I/preview) that considered Zotero, Mendeley, Google Scholar, CB2BIB, Metadata Extraction Tool, pdfssa4met, pdfmeat, GNU libextractor, FITS, Apache Tika, XPDF, PDFTOHTML, pdf2xml, CiteSeerX, and Paperpile. This list seems to leave out some other solutions, although it is possible that they rely on the same underlying technology. This answers to this [TeX.SX question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42361/is-there-a-citation-manager-which-plays-nicely-with-bibtex-and-has-automatic-met) suggests BibDesk and JabRef do metadata extraction. [Papers](http://www.papersapp.com/mac/) also seems to do metadata extraction. This [blog](http://musingsaboutlibrarianship.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/extracting-metadata-from-pdfs-comparing.html#.VCKGOuK5NFE) reviews the metadata extraction performance of WizFolio.

There is also [Mr. dLib](http://docear.org/papers/Mr.%20dLib%20-%20A%20Machine%20Readable%20Digital%20Library%20--%20preprint.pdf), [pdfextract](https://github.com/CrossRef/pdfextract) and [TeamBeam](http://www.dlib.org/dlib/july12/kern/07kern.html) which seem to have scholarly papers associated with them and therefore seem to be misssed by the JISC review (or developed afterwards). I also found [exiftool](http://rossmounce.co.uk/2013/01/06/pdf-metadata-using-exiftool/).

Answer (score 5):

[cb2Bib](http://www.molspaces.com/d_cb2bib-overview.php) is a tool to extract bibtex entries from PDF files.

The following will command extract bibtex entries from PDF file  using cb2Bib command line

`c2bconsole --doc2bib paper2.pdf references.bib  --sloppy`

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: This is a short version of an [answer posted at tex.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344310/9075). This solution is not perfect, but might be a good start. I am one of the authors of JabRef and like open source development.

[JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/) is an [MIT-licensed](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/blob/master/LICENSE.md) open-source BibTeX and BibLaTeX bibliographic manager actively developed on [GitHub](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/). It offers the functionality to import bibliographic data from PDFs.

1. Create or open a .bib file.
2. Go to "Quality" -> "Find unlinked files".
   [image: menu entry for starting find linked files]
3. The "Find unlinked files" dialog opens.
   [image: Find unlinked files dialog]
4. Choose a directory using the "Browse" button.
5. Click on "Scan directory".
6. In "Select files", the files not yet contained in the database are shown.
   [image: scan result]
7. To create entries for all files, click on "Apply".
8. For each file, an import dialog is shown
   [image: metadata dialog]

   The dialog shows the XMP metadata stored in the PDF in the area "XMP-metadata".
   If this data fits your needs, select "Create entry based on XMP data".
   Typically, the XMP-metadata is not good enough.
   Choose "Create entry based on content".
9. Click on "OK" to start the import
10. A dialog asking for the link is opened
    [image: Link to file dialog]
    You can choose "Leave file in its current directory" to keep the file where it is. Typically, this is that what one wants.
    In case you choose "Move file to file directory", you can also choose to rename the file to the generated BibTeX key.
11. Press OK to link the file to the BibTeX entry
12. This happens for each file. After that, the "Find unlinked files" dialog is shown. Just click on "Close" to close it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at pdf-extract:
https://github.com/CrossRef/pdfextract

It doesn't seem to be very actively maintained, but promises to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  As far as I can tell, pdfextract is designed to extract references in a paper, so it wouldn't give you a bibtex entry for the paper that you run it on.